# Build fails when deploying to netlify Field "banner" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields

Tags: graphql, gatsby, hosting, netlify

I have a gatsby project. It builds and develops perfectly in my local machine. But when I'm trying to build it in netlify it shows the following error:

```
2:28:17 AM: error There was an error in your GraphQL query:
2:28:17 AM:       Field "banner" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.
2:28:17 AM:       This can happen if you e.g. accidentally added { } to the field "banner". If you didn't expect "banner" to be of type "String" make sure that your input source and/or plugin is correct.
      However, if you expect "value" to exist, the field might be accessible in another subfield. Please try your query in GraphiQL.
2:28:17 AM:       It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields.
2:28:17 AM: not finished Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs - 38.475s
2:28:17 AM: failed extract queries from components - 2.397s
2:28:17 AM: ​
2:28:17 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
2:28:17 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:28:17 AM: ​
2:28:17 AM:   Error message
2:28:17 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: gatsby build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
2:28:17 AM: ​
2:28:17 AM:   Error location
2:28:17 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
2:28:17 AM:   gatsby build
```

Why is this and how to resolve it?